# shared transition from activity's fragment's listview's custom base adapter button click to another activity is not working

Tags: android, shared-element-transition

I am using listview with custom BaseAdapter to display various item. The listview is inside FragmentA and FragmentA is displayed using MainActivity's view pager. Now i want shared element transion from custom adapter button onclick to Main2Activity.I have searched a lot in SO and tried but none of them solve my issue. when i click button inside custom adapter the Main2Activity is not displaying at all but in that moment if i rotate my mobile screen then its getting displayed. I have checked my code very minutely but could not find whats wrong in it. So please help me in this context.

```
public class MySBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Map<String,Object>> data=new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
public LayoutInflater inflater=null;  
String itemNo, itemId;
Activity activity;
public MySBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, Object>> data, Activity thisactitity, String itemno, String itemid){
    mContext=context;
    this.data=data;
    this.itemNo=itemno;
    this.itemId=itemid;
    activity=thisactitity;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imvb.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmp=imvb.getDrawingCache();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("bitmap_data",bmp);                    intent.putExtra("item_name",itemname.getText().toString());                   
                intent.putExtra("item_num",itemNo);
                intent.putExtra("item_id",itemId);                   
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create((View)imvb,"phototrans");
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, pair1);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                }else {
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

---

### Custom adapter class

```
public class MySBaseAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Context mContext;
private List<Map<String,Object>> data=new ArrayList<Map<String, Object>>();
public LayoutInflater inflater=null;  
String itemNo, itemId;
Activity activity;
public MySBaseAdapter(Context context, List<Map<String, Object>> data, Activity thisactitity, String itemno, String itemid){
    mContext=context;
    this.data=data;
    this.itemNo=itemno;
    this.itemId=itemid;
    activity=thisactitity;
    inflater=(LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
@Override
public View getView(int position, final View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
item.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                imvb.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bmp=imvb.getDrawingCache();
                Intent intent = new Intent(mContext, Main2Activity.class);
                intent.putExtra("bitmap_data",bmp);                    intent.putExtra("item_name",itemname.getText().toString());                   
                intent.putExtra("item_num",itemNo);
                intent.putExtra("item_id",itemId);                   
                intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Pair<View, String> pair1 = Pair.create((View)imvb,"phototrans");
                ActivityOptionsCompat options = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation(activity, pair1);
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mContext.startActivity(intent, options.toBundle());
                }else {
                    mContext.startActivity(intent);
                }
            }
        });
```

---

### Main2Activity

```
public class Main2Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
Context pContext;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_CONTENT_TRANSITIONS);
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main31);
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){
        prorileimage.setTransitionName("phototrans");
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

What is **item**, is it a button or some other view? If its not button have you set its **clickable** property **true** in xml file? You can print log inside the click listener.

One more thing I am concern about it as [this](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/02/continuous-shared-element-transitions.html) document says, transition determines how views transits between activity or fragments; and you have taken bitmap so will it give transition or not. I am not sure :

**A shared element transition determines how views that are present in two fragments transition between them. For example, an image that is displayed on an ImageView on both Fragment A and Fragment B transitions from A to B when B becomes visible.**